# How to draw straight line between two UIButtons in iOS?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to draw straight line between two UIButtons. When we touch button 1 the line will appear in black color; when we touch button 3 the line will become red; and when we touch button 2 the line will become Green and end on Button two. So that line will be visible connected two buttons only button 1 and button 2.

Now I want when I click button 4 the new line will appear in orange color. The previous line was end on button-2 and this will be the new line. And same this will connect if I touch button 5.

Same just like kids play matching the quiz game.

Means Tv belongs to electronics (Right), sky belong to Glass (wrong). Just like that I need to connect Button 1 and Button 2 , Button 4 and Button 5.

Any idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: the `CoreGraphics` can give you very handy basis to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to place some uiimageviews around your buttons, and based on the ibaction of each button, add or remove images (with different coloured lines) to/from your uiimageviews, as you need.

Comment: Any demo available on the net?

Comment: Are you familiar with storyboard and linking the outlets?

Comment: you add your buttons to a view controller. you add your uiimageviews as you need, adjust their sizes. drag outlets for all uiimageviews. drag ibactions for your button. for each button's action, you would set something like self.imageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"], etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of images. Just write your logic for replacing, hiding and unhiding the images. It would be a simpler approach.

Comment: Sir can you please write some code or give any reference link. I also said Mr. Calin he gave me the same advice but I am not able to do this. I need some reference. Without reference I cant write this code.

Comment: You can use the XIB interface for designing the views with button and can take the outlets for those properties and when you click on any button then you have to manage those outlets accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
-(void)drawLineWithStartPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint WithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// Set the starting point of the shape.
[aPath moveToPoint:startpoint;

// Draw the lines.
[aPath addLineToPoint:endPoint;
[aPath closePath];
 aPath.lineWidth = 2;
  [aPath fill]; 
  [aPath stroke];

}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I am not able to implement this code as this is new for me so I dont know how to use this. How to use UIBezierPath? Can you please elaborate this code, what is going in .h and viewDidLoad and how drawLineWithStartPoint method will be called? Please elaborate sir so that I and other people who are new in iOS can learn.

Comment: Please refer to the docs, we are not here to teach you but guide you.